# How to add an ID to a select > option element that is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I add an ID to a select > option:selected HTML element?

Here is my code so far.

```
<!-- select time zone -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h3 id="stepOne"><b>Step 1:</b> Select your Time Zone</h3>
            <select class="form-control" name="timeZone" id="getTimeZone" onchange="getTimeZone()">
                <?php foreach ($time_zones as $key => $array) : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($array as $offset => $zone) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $offset; ?>"><?php echo $zone; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end select timezone -->

    <!-- get timezone from dropdown -->
    <script>
        function getTimeZone() {
            // if option is selected add an ID attribute
            // then get that id attributes inner html
            var id = $("#getTimeZone").children("option:selected").attr("timeZoneSelected");
            var timeZone = document.getElementById("getTimeZone").value;
            document.getElementById("showTimeZone").innerHTML = timeZone;
            document.getElementById("timeZoneField").value = timeZone;
            document.getElementById("stepOne").className = "text-success";
        }
    </script>
    <!-- end get timezone from dropdown -->
```

So basically I am looping through a list of time zones. When the user selects a time zone I want to add an ID to the option, e.g `id="timeZoneSelected"`.

Then I want to grab the innerHTML of that specific option element.

As you can see my code is not working, specifically:

```
var id = $("#getTimeZone").children("option:selected").attr("timeZoneSelected");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't use an `id` for this - they are intended to be static. Use a class instead. Also, it seems like you just want the `text()` of the selected option, as none of them have a `timeZoneSelected` attribute

Comment: Okay, advice heeded, but I only want one element in my entire html page to have the "timeZoneSelected" attribute... so I thought that was what IDs were for.

Comment: To what end? It's a very odd requirement to put a dynamic identifier on an `option` element which can be quite simply retrieved using `option:selected`

Comment: Okay, I am trying to display the users selected time zone to the user after they have selected it. The value of all of the options are the time zone offset in seconds... so my only way of 'getting' the user friendly time zone string is by getting the <select> tags inner html... however when I do that I get the HTML of every single one of my timezones, not pretty. So if I add an ID to the exact timezone that the user selected then I can get the innerHTML of that id which will be the userfriendly timezone string. Time zones are a royal...

Comment: Ok - I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you can simply retrieve the `value` and inner text of the selected option within the `change` event handler. There's no need to dynamically update identifiers or class attributes. Try this:

```js
$('#getTimeZone').change(function() {
  var name = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  var offset = this.value;
  
  $('#name').html(name);
  $('#offset').html(offset);
  $('#stepOne').addClass('text-success');
});
```

```css
.text-success { color: #0c0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h3 id="stepOne"><b>Step 1:</b> Select your Time Zone</h3>
    <select class="form-control" name="timeZone" id="getTimeZone">
      <option value="-6">CST</option>
      <option value="0">GMT</option>
      <option value="+8">SGT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="name"></div>
<div id="offset"></div>
```

Note that I amended your code to use unobtrusive event handlers as `on*` event attributes are considered outdated.

Comment: Absolutely stunning Rory,  that code makes perfect sense now, thank you so much.

Comment: Good stuff, glad to help